# Converting existing PC into a VM with Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'd like to convert my laptop (Windows Vista) into a VirtualBox VM. I think there is a utility for VMWare, but is it possible to do with Virtual Box?

Also, do I need another (host) PC to run the conversion process?

Comment: +1: Very interesting question, I'd love to see this one get answered!

Comment: Just for linking, this related question: [Is it possible to “virtualize” an existing PC?](http://superuser.com/q/481960/102047)

Answer (score 8):

I like to use [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) for creating virtual disk. This virtual disk can then be used inside any created VirtualBox virtual machine.

This tool will also "reset" drivers on Windows so they will boot and detect their new virtual environment without any issues.

Comment: That is very good. Imaging the drive is an obvious option, but drivers would definitely be an issue. I like that this tool is aware of that and can handle it.

Comment: Note that there is a max disk size supported by Microsoft Virtual PC of 127GB. Don't know if VirtualBox has any similar limitation.

Comment: @MZB: VHD as a format supports disk up to 2 TB. VirtualBox shares that limitation. If your drives are smaller than that and virtualization environment is newer than grandpa Virtual PC, you should be fine.

Comment: Where is the option in Virtualbox to open a vhd?  this answer suggests its more complicated http://superuser.com/questions/636078/create-disk-image-of-c-drive-and-run-on-vmware-virtual-machine

Comment: @barlop: VHD in VirtualBox can be opened from the same dialog you use to add any other disk type supported by it (Settings, Storage, Add, Existing). Conversion to vdmk you refer to in that other question is only needed if you want to use VMWare.

Comment: @JosipMedved well, I just tried it but got a BSOD that flashed on screen to quickly to even read it

Answer (score 5):

If no one else comes up with an answer / all in one tool then I would suggest simply using the [VMWare converter tool](https://www.vmware.com/tryvmware/?p=converter&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CEUQFjAC&url=http://www.vmware.com/go/getconverter&rct=j&q=vmware%20converter&ei=IVPNTb36No-aOu7Q1PoM&usg=AFQjCNH3Et0HlSZPzkw2VZxLVZoNZ_yY5g) and importing the virtual machine to Virtual Box.

Using this tool, you do not need to use a second machine.

Comment: -1: The OP already knows that this exists.

Comment: @Mark Szymanski - yes, but it doesn't look like he knows that it can be imported, and not knowing of a better tool, I am letting him know that he can import it!

Comment: Ok, undone my downvote, and replaced it with a +1!